# Is possible to redirect urls outside joomla with sh404sef without htaccess enabled?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, redirect

Is possible to redirect urls **wihthout** htaccess enabled for sh404sef (example: from `http://domain/courses.php TO http://domain/en/courses) ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What is `sh404sef`?

Comment: sh404sef is a extensions to joomla (http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef) that aims to improve SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work because of 2 reasons:

- http://domain/en/courses is actually a URL that can only exist when .htaccess is enabled (if .htaccess was disabled then the URL will be: http://domain/index.php/en/courses )
- The first URL ( domain/courses.php ) is not a Joomla URL, and sh404SEF only allows redirection of a Joomla URL to another Joomla URL.

Comment: This is what I believe as well, I just wanted it confirmed. Thank you!